# how to solve this equation for $ f(x) $ in a functional equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-equations, fundamental-solution

given the functional  infinite equation

$$ g(x)= \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}f(\frac{x}{n})log(n) $$

the function $ g(x) $ is know

if the log term wasn't there i know the solution but can i really invert this equation and obtain $ f(x) $ ?

thanks

Applying the Mellin transform to both sites i get ·$ G(s)= -\zeta ' (s)F(s) $

what can i do which math should i use ?

Comment: Where does $x$ lie? For example, $x=0$ cannot be in the domain.

Comment: $\frac{1}{\zeta'(s)}$ is not a Dirichlet series because $\zeta'(\infty) = 0$. 

To recover $f$ from $g$ you'll need (a distribution) $h$ such that  $\frac{-1}{\zeta'(s)} = \int_0^\infty h(x) x^{-s-1}dx$ , obtaining (if it converges) $f(x) = \int_0^\infty g(y) h(x/y) \frac{dy}{y}$